# How to get cppcheck-results into SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, cppcheck

We use **cpp-check** and **SonarQube 6.0** and want to inject the results of cppcheck into the system. Cppcheck runs fine and produces an xml-file with results. However Cpp-check and SonarQube are **not running on the same machine.**

Is it sufficient to set something in 
Administration > C++(Community) > CodeCode analysis > Cppcheckreports ?

We put the name of the xml into that field - but how should SonarQube find that? 
What are we missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SonarQube and Cppcheck don't have to run on the same machine. But the Cppcheck report *does* need to be available to the analysis. If you can't run analysis on the machine where Cppcheck runs, then you just need to set up some process (FTP? Sneakernet?) to get the file where it needs to go.

This all assumes you have the [Cppcheck plugin installed](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-cppcheck) in SonarQube, as well as some plugin, such as <strike>[SonarC++](https://www.sonarsource.com/why-us/products/languages/cpp.html)($)</strike>, which declares the language.

**2023 Edit** C++ analysis is available in all [commercial editions](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/) of SonarQube, and on SonarCloud, which is free for open source projects

Comment: Is there a cppchcek plugin compatible with SonarQube 7.9

Comment: I don't think so, but you should bug the CppCheck folks directly about that.

Comment: link SonarC++($) is dead

Answer (score 1):

The cppcheck plugin for SonarQube has not been maintained for 6 years now and won't work with resent versions of SonarQube. https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-cppcheck/issues/6#issuecomment-377563241